# Why can't I choose "Latest iOS" for the base SDK?

Tags: ios, xcode4.6

In the project editor pane, with "Build Settings" selected, and with either the project or the target selected, the choices for Base SDK don't show any drop-down arrows. I can double click on the field and type any text into the box but I remember that it used to have drop down choices and the recommendation was to choose "Latest iOS". But now there are no choices and apparently there is no way to enter Latest iOS. Is there some configuration option I might have changed that caused the choices to be removed?

What is in the box now is the text "iphoneos". By double clicking and entering various strings I see that anything is valid if it begins with iphoneos, no matter what text follows that. For example "iphoneosxyzxyz" is valid. But if I enter any other text (for example "iphone" or "Latest iOS") and try to build I get an error that says: "The scheme 'Metronome' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination iPhone 6.1 Simulator. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode."

(I'm using Apple's Metronome demo project for testing this problem.)

This is with Xcode 4.6.3.

I have another Mac also with Xcode 4.6.3 and if I run the same project on it I see the drop down choices and I can choose Latest iOS and it builds ok.

So the question is, did I change something to create this behavior? Or is my Xcode damaged and I should reinstall it?

screen shot showing what happens when I click on the field where I think a drop down should appear:
[image]

While doing this screen shot I noticed that also there is not a drop down field on the Architectures line. If I click on "$(ARCH_STANDARD_32_BIT)" I get an editable text field instead of a drop down choice.

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of this.

Comment: Xcode is often buggy. Have you tried to quit and re-launch?

Comment: I added a screen shot. Yes I tried relaunching Xcode but it's the same. I also tried rebooting the machine and doing Product/Clean.

Comment: Another clue: I created a new user, logged in as that user, and made a new Xcode project. Now the Xcode Build Settings are normal i.e. they have the choice arrows. I conclude from this that there is a configuration or preference file somewhere that it causing the "abnormal" Build Settings. And the Xcode image itself is probably not damaged.

Answer (score 1):

Select **Editor** in the Xcode menu, then select **Show Values** (instead of **Show Definitions**)